# Maya-Python manipMoveContext

Tags: python, maya

Right now I'm trying to make a script that changes the pivot orientation in Maya. (This feature is already in the Maya Modeling Toolbox but I want to make a custom and simplified version of it) However I'm getting issues with my function. This is the code:

```
cmds.optionMenu(label = 'Pivot', changeCommand = pivotOrient)

cmds.menuItem( label='Object', )
cmds.menuItem( label='World')
cmds.menuItem( label='Component' )
cmds.menuItem( label='Normal' )


def pivotOrient( p ):
    if p == 'Object':
        cmds.manipMoveContext(e= True, mode= 0)
    elif p == 'World':
        cmds.manipMoveContext(e= True, mode= 2)
    elif p == 'Component':
        cmds.manipMoveContext(e= True, mode= 10)
    else:
        cmds.manipMoveContext(e= True, mode= 3)
```

It says **"# Error: RuntimeError: file  line 40: No object name specified. #"**

Can you help me with this problem? I'm sorry I'm still a newbie at Python and Maya scripting. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you might want to change the title of your question, as the error you're getting is related to the way you're using the `manipMoveContext` command; nothing to do with drop-downs :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `manipMoveContext` command requires the first argument to specify the context, when in `edit` or `query` mode (see: http://help.autodesk.com/cloudhelp/2016/ENU/Maya-Tech-Docs/CommandsPython/manipMoveContext.html#hExamples).

In the simplest case scenario, you can use `'Move'` as the first argument for your calls, as such:
`cmds.manipMoveContext('Move', e=True, mode=0)`

But for less trivial scenarios (or even just to generalize your code and make it more robust) you need to understand how manipulators and contexts work and add some logic to your `pivotOrient` function.

Merely as a hint to what I mean, you can have a look at these:

- https://forum.highend3d.com/t/how-to-get-the-current-manipulators-location/2822
- http://forums.cgsociety.org/showthread.php?t=908417

Also, try playing with this:

```
curctx = cmds.currentCtx()
print curctx
if cmds.superCtx(curctx, ex=1):
    ctx = cmds.superCtx(curctx, q=1)
    typ = cmds.contextInfo(ctx, q=1, c=1)
    print ctx, typ
```

Comment: That doc actually too old ;) http://help.autodesk.com/cloudhelp/2016/ENU/Maya-Tech-Docs/CommandsPython/manipMoveContext.html

Comment: you're right @Achayan, I just edited the answer. I admit that I rarely check for the Maya edition, when looking at the docs... for this kind of stuff, it didn't change in a while... :)